# export Java EE Web Application as JAR

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, packaging

This might be a weird question but I am curious about this:

I want to create a Java EE Web Project, that I can package into a JAR file (`<packaging>jar</packaging>` instead of `<packaging>war</packaging>`).

In other words, I want to include the Java EE web server inside a JAR (built by maven).

Inside the WebServer I want to use Servlets like I can use them when I package it to a WAR file but without requireing the devices that execute the JAR to have a Web server installed where they can deploy my JAR.

I want something like an executeable JAR that contains the server and runs it without the need to install something else.

Is there a (ideally light-weight) server that works within a JAR file or any other possibility to create a JAR file like this?

Comment: Spring boot. Or embed jetty. Or use spring boot with jetty.

Comment: Hammock project combined with Capsule for packaging into an executable jar is quite nice and lightweight for Java EE apps.

Comment: You could use [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io) for this purpose. You can build an exe that will run without even having Java installed. That said, product recommendations are not supposed to be in the scope of stack overflow questions and we should probably close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use vanilla Java EE, you can use an Embedded Jetty Server or Embedded Tomcat Server:

Here is an example with Embedded Tomcat and Maven:

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>

        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.19</jsf.version>
        <tomcat.version>9.0.21</tomcat.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>app</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>app-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.company.app.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mainClass:

```java
package org.company.app;




import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

import java.io.File;

public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String webappPath = new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath();
        final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        final StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", webappPath);
        System.out.println(ctx
        );
        // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
        // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
        final String targetClassesPath = new File("target/classes").getAbsolutePath();
        final WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(//
                resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", //
                targetClassesPath, "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

and the rest as usual java ee development

Comment: Where is your `</dependencies>`?

Comment: Also, I had to add `tomcat-embed-jasper` and `tomcat-embed-el` to my dependencies and `tomcat.getConnector();` to my main.

Comment: and I removed `jsf-api` and `jsf-api` from the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I probably didn't pay attention when copying the pom. I editted the answer.